# Como destacar texto (mudar cor) em C ANSI

Tags: c

Boa noite... Estou na duvida de como usar a função textcolor em c mas não a encontrei na biblioteca conio... alguém sabe onde fica localizada essa função ou se tiver que cria-la como fazer? obrigado

Comment: Esta função só deve funcionar em copilador turbo C ou dev C. Vai ter que criar um método que troca a cor através das opções de cores do prompt.

Comment: Poderia postar seu código na pergunta?

Comment: então... vou aplicar isso em vários programas n tem código especifico preciso um tipo a função textcolor do pascal que muda a cor do prox caracter ate a prox função textcolor sem afetar as informações já impressas

Comment: Vc quer mudar a cor de todo o texto impresso no prompt?

Comment: isso so que so a parti da linha de execução

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você estiver utilizando o Sistema Operacional `Windows`, você pode incluir a biblioteca `windows.h` e utilizar:

```
typedef enum{BLACK,BLUE,GREEN,CYAN,RED,MAGENTA,BROWN,LIGHTGRAY,DARKGRAY,
LIGHTBLUE,LIGHTGREEN,LIGHTCYAN,LIGHTRED,LIGHTMAGENTA,YELLOW,WHITE} COLORS;

static int __BACKGROUND = BLACK;
static int __FOREGROUND = LIGHTGRAY;

void textcolor (int color)
{
    __FOREGROUND = color;
    SetConsoleTextAttribute (GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
    color + (__BACKGROUND << 4));
}
```

Podes também utilizar a biblioteca `curses.h`:

```
start_color();      
init_pair(1, COLOR_RED, COLOR_BLACK);
attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
printw("Mensagem com cor!");
attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));
```

Comment: vlw cara ajudou

Answer (score 1):

Dependendo do SO que você usa, tem implementações diferentes. Sistemas que em *MS-DOS*, possuem a biblioteca `conio.h`, entretanto sistemas *Unix* possui o `curses.h`.

Outra forma é escrevendo diretamente os caracteres responsáveis pelas cores do seu texto (No caso de sistemas *Unix*):

**Efeitos**

```
/*****************************EFECTS***************************************/
#define NONE        "\033[0m"
#define BOLD        "\033[1m"
#define HALFBRIGHT  "\033[2m"
#define UNDERSCORE  "\033[4m"
#define BLINK       "\033[5m"
#define REVERSE     "\033[7m"

/*****************************COLORS***************************************/
#define C_BLACK     "\033[30m"
#define C_RED       "\033[31m"
#define C_GREEN     "\033[32m"
#define C_YELLOW    "\033[33m"
#define C_BLUE      "\033[34m"
#define C_MAGENTA   "\033[35m"
#define C_CYAN      "\033[36m"
#define C_GRAY      "\033[37m"

/***************************BACKGROUNDS************************************/
#define BG_BLACK    "\033[40m"
#define BG_RED      "\033[41m"
#define BG_GREEN    "\033[42m"
#define BG_YELLOW   "\033[43m"
#define BG_BLUE     "\033[44m"
#define BG_MAGENTA  "\033[45m"
#define BG_CYAN     "\033[46m"
#define BG_GRAY     "\033[47m"
```

Essas combinações de caracteres, pode ser usadas para limpar a tela, enviar sinais de encerramento, posicionar o cursor, entre outros.

**Usando efeitos**

```
const char *string = "texto escrito em verde!";
printf("%s%s%s",C_GREEN,string,NONE);
```

O `NONE` serve para limpar qualquer estilização feita, ele volta o estilo do texto ao padrão do terminal.

Answer (score -1):

Dependendendo do Sistema Operacional, não há a implementação do  `conio.h`, basicamente depende se ele foi compilado em MS-DOS ou não. Provavelmente, o sistema que você tá usando não foi.

Nesse caso, use `#include <curses.h>`, que te dará quase todas as funcionalidades que o  `conio.h`. Mas se ele não estiver instalado, pode ser que você tenha que procurar esse arquivo na internet.