# Como colocar cor no texto

Tags: c

Esse é o enunciado: Numa faculdade, os alunos com média pelo menos 7,0 são aprovados, aqueles com média inferior a 3,0 são reprovados e os
demais ficam de recuperação. Dadas as duas notas de um aluno, elabore um programa em C que informe sua situação. Use as cores
azul, vermelho e amarelo para as mensagens “aprovado”, “reprovado” e “recuperação”, respectivamente.

A logica eu consegui fazer menos a parte de colocar a cor. Obrigado desde já!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main (){

float n1,n2,media;
printf ("Digite a primeira nota:");
scanf ("%f",&n1);
printf ("Digite a segunda nota:");
scanf ("%f",&n2);

media = (n1+n2)/2;

if (media>=7)
printf ("APROVADO");

else{

if (media <3)

printf ("REPROVADO");

else{
    
    if (media >=3)
    printf ("RECUPERACAO");
}
}
}
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/157898/como-destacar-texto-mudar-cor-em-c-ansi

Answer (score 2):

É possível colocar a cor nos elementos da seguinte forma, para a cor vermelho, amarelo e azul basta colocar as seguintes funções:

```
//vermelho
printf("\33[1;31m");
printf("Hello World");
//azul
printf("\33[1;34m");
printf("Hello World");
//amarelo
printf("\33[0;33m");
printf("Hello World");
```

Para imprimir essas cores eu utilizei [este link](http://web.theurbanpenguin.com/adding-color-to-your-output-from-c/), que você pode utilizar para consulta.